# Keep having to run aspnet_regiis

Tags: iis, .net

Not sure if this belongs here or in SO but here goes anyway...

We have a CruiseControl.NET server that performs nightly builds on or applications and then publishes the resulting output to the IIS instance on the same box - this acts as out test deployment for QA.

Everything has been running fine for months until we moved to a new server (Win2003 R2 SP1) - actually a VM.

Now, whenever the nightly build publishes to IIS we get an error in the browser stating **The compiler failed with error code 128**. This never happened on the old server!

Running **aspnet_regiis -i** will get the site back online but I'm baffled as to why IIS seems to have forgotten all about .NET as the result of a simple file copy.

I've reviewed the publish stage of the build process and moved from the good old-fashioned batch script to a 'cleaner' nAnt script but the problem remains.

If I run the above command, clear out the events logs and then access the site a new event appears:

```
The configuration information of the performance library
"C:\WINDOWS\system32\infoctrs.dll" for the "InetInfo" service does not match 
the trusted performance library information stored in the registry. 
The functions in this library will not be treated as trusted.
```

But the site does still load without any problems. If I then run either of the publish scripts (.bat or .build) then access the site another identical event appears and the compilation error is displayed (running aspnet_regiis fix it though).

If I manually delete the old files and copy across the new ones then once again the Compiler Error is displayed in the browser.

Now the quick fix is to run aspnet_regiis as part of the build script but frankly that just smells to bad.

**[Edit 12/11/09]: I've been kicking this around for a little while now and still don't really know why it is happening. I've reinstalled IIS and .NET 2.0 & 3.0 (3.5 is not needed!) but the problem persisted. Finally I tried deploying the application using files built via a 'Release' build (as opposed to 'Debug') and this appears to have resolved the problem - but I don't know why.**

**I'll find out tomorrow morning after the nightly builds have run in anger so hopefully I have some good news waiting for me. Assuming this is the problem, why should it make a difference? This process was running fine for months on the physical server - why should it be causing problems on the VM.?**

Anyone have any ideas, suggestions or solutions..?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It could be related to the default framework of a web site, 1.1 or 2.0. aspnet_regiis sets the framework version.

If you:

- Install windows
- Run all windows updates
- Add application role

OR

- Install windows
- Add application role
- Run all windows updates

Then the default framework is not the same. It could also be that you install is setting the framework version.

Comment: Not heard of that before but then I'm a Dev not a SysAdmin ;-) I'll check when I get into work tomorrow

Comment: Didn't get to it as quickly as I'd hoped - now the dev manager wants to demo from the test servers it's a priority, so I'm looking now. Will post updates back here if i get to the bottom of it :-\

Answer (score 1):

The VM itself isn't being rolled back, is it?

Comment: The VM is backed up on a regular basis but not rolled back. It just seems to happen whenever I publish the build, i.e. not related to backup times etc.